# Sql search > Works on Mysql doesn't on SQLITE

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

recently i've started programming on android sqlite and I was debugging my sql commands with Mysql Workbench.

In one of my commands I've got this :

```
"Select itens.name_item , itens.pot_item from region,itens,item_regions where region.cod_region = "+id+" and itens.cod_item = item_region.cod_item;"
```

basically I have 3 tables.

**region**, **itens** and uniting with foreign keys those 2 inside of **item_region**.

What i want is by already having the region code, get the **name** and **power** of the registered itens in item_regions.

Sry if it's a little confusing, i'm very rusted on my english

Comment: Ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead. Your query would produce a semi-Cartesian product with the cross join to the `region` table, and it's very unlikely you want that. If `cod_region` is in the association table, you should be able to remove the reference to the `region` table entirely. Beware of SQL Injection vulnerabilities: including an "unsafe" value in the SQL text can make your code vulnerable; the `id` variable needs to be properly escaped, or better yet, make use of prepared statement with  a bind placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an inner join:

```
SELECT name_item, pot_item FROM items 
INNER JOIN item_region ON items.cod_item = item_region.cod_item
WHERE item_region.cod_region = ?;
```

I assume from your example you have the region code in the item_region table, otherwise you'll have to join in the region table as well to compare to the id.

Also be careful that the value of the variable id is sanitized so you don't expose your application to SQL injection.

Comment: Don't sanitize. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm now using "?" instead of the value, but i'm also going to research about this parameterized queries. Thanks again for the tips.